# How to return list<string> inside of c++ dll to C# program MarshallDirectiveException

Tags: c#, c++, dll, marshalling, unmanaged

I want to run c++ function on c# .net program and return to c# type list but i got marshall directive exception, i researched that and c++ 's list is not same with c# list but i cannot find. What is c# equivalent of the list. I found list equivalent as Linkedlist in c# but it was not correct.

C++ Header

```
 extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) list<string> x_browseCan();
```

Cpp file

```
list<string> x_browseCan() {

    browseCan(_c, 2);
    return _c->response.object_list;
}
```

_c->response->object_list

```
list<string> object_list;
```

C#

```
[DllImport(@"C:\Users\serhan.erkovan\source\repos\kkkkk_v2\x64\Debug\kkkkk_v2.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern List<string> x_browseCan();

    private void Browse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<string> object_list = new List<string>();
            object_list = x_browseCan();
        }
```

Are there easy way to access equivalent of datatypes ?
I search P/Invoke on http://www.pinvoke.net/ but i cant understand

Comment: You cannot use [DllImport] to call this function, a C++/CLI wrapper is required to convert an std::list

Comment: Okey i have to return string list, how can i do that ? @HansPassant

Comment: You need a C++/CLI wrapper, as @HansPassant said … It's just a small function which takes in an `std::list<std::string>` and converts it to/returns a `List<String^>`

Comment: Okey i did not understand at firs comment :) I researched that thanks for information

Comment: @ChrisMM Hey Chris hello, i try to create `C++/CLI wrapper` but when i use `Common Language Runtime Support /clr` i cant use Thread and Mutex classes. Could you help me about that ?

Comment: Make the wrapper completely separate from the rest of the code. Is only responsibility should be to convert between the two languages. Have it call the C++ function, get the result, convert it to CLI equivalent, and return that. The wrapper should be a separate project, so that it can use CLI without affecting anything else.

Comment: I tried to do something but i cant handle with some situation , if you want to look, this is link https://stackoverflow.com/q/59456109/10711011 @ChrisMM